# Synthesized properties changing behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a bunch of properties like this:
Myobject.property

Now I want to change how these properties are calculated.  Can I do this while still keeping the . syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can define the property with @property in your .h file, and instead of having @synthesize in your .m file, you can just define your own getter / setter:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
        @private NSString* iVar_;
}

@property (readwrite, assign) NSString* iVar;
@end
```

Then in your .m:

```
@implementation YourClass 

- (NSString*) iVar {
    // Put your custom logic here.
    return iVar_;
}

- (void) setIVar:(NSString*)value {
    // Put your custom logic here.
    // Note: be aware of retain counts... you may need to call release on iVar before assigning it a new value.
    iVar_ = value;
}

@end
```

Comment: If you're manually writing your own methods, there's no need for `@dynamic`